# error while trying to see articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am getting this error while going into articles/new.

[image]

my code :

new.html.erb :

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>
<%if @article.error.any? %>
<ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li> <%= msg %> </li>
</ul>



<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>

    <%= f.text_field:title %>

</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description  %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>

</p>
    end
```

my articles_controller.erb file :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @article = Article.new 
   end

   def create
     @article = Article.new(article_params)
     if  @article.save
       flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
       redirect_to (@article)
     else
       render :new
     end 
   end

    private 
    def article_params 
       params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

ask me for any other files if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be the "end" word that slip on your `new.html.erb` file. You are missing the `<%` `%>` surrounding the `end`.

Remember that all ruby code in a view must be inside of `<%` `%>` or `<%=` `%>`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying can you be a bit more clearer with an example

Comment: He's close, but the real issue is that the word `end` at the very bottom of `new.html.erb` should be `<% end %>`

Comment: Yeah @jrabramson, you are right. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your erb file has many errors

- `if @article.errors.any?` not `if @article.error.any?`
- you are not closing the the blocks of if and each, you are also closing the block of the form wrongly.

check the code below.

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li> <%= msg %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field:title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description  %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```